# How to read/write floating-point values to/from a byte array?

Tags: c, floating-point, memory-layout

I'm sure this question has been asked many times before, so I did a quick search and found [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Structure_of_a_floating-point_number) that explains the structure of a floating point value.

I'm sending and receiving data across a network that consists of some floating point values (for a game), which leads me to the following questions:

1. Do I have to worry about endianness?
2. If endianness matters, how can I extract these values without doing a `*(float*)` cast or a union? (such as the trick with bit shifting for integers)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Floating point endianness is discussed some here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness

Answer (score 0):

If you write out a floating-point value straight from memory, then, yes, you will have to handle endianness.

There are thousand of ways you can handle this. One way often used by network protocols is to read a structure into a byte buffer, swap all elements (if the endianness of the host machine does not match that of the protocol) and then treat it as a normal host-machine structure.